# why can't I use assignment operator inside a constructor in a class C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that store credit cards data. The card number is 16 digits and 3 space characters to separate every 4 digits. In the DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR, I get an error when I assign the array characters to blank:

**Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)**

A little help please? :)

```
#ifndef creditCardInfo_hpp
#define creditCardInfo_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class CreditCardInfo {
private:
    string name;
    char *cardNumber; // points to array of numbers
    int cvv;
    string address;
    int numDigit = 20;   // number of digits
    
public:
    // Constructor
    CreditCardInfo(){
        name = "none";
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            cardNumber[i] = ' ';
        }
        cvv = 0;
        address = "none";
    }
```

Comment: Hint: Where is cardNumber initialized?

Comment: According to a comment in your code, `cardNumber` points to an array of numbers. Where did you allocate the array that `cardNumber` ostensibly points to?

Comment: Why does `cardNumber` have to point to an array rather than be an array itself (like `char cardNumber[20]`)?

Comment: Ohh right! I'm still trying to figure out what's the difference between an array and a pointer pointing to the beginning of an array

Comment: @Sam a *pointer* has to point at something, or be null to point at nothing.  An *array* is a something that can be pointed at.

Comment: `cadNumber[i]` uses the value of `cardNumber`. So you need to assign `cardNumber` a value before you attempt to access `cardNumber[i]`!

Answer (score 2):

`(code=1, address=0x0)` this part here is the issue

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cardNumber[i] = ' '; // <----- cardNumber is null
    }
```

Comment: In the constructor, `cardNumber` is uninitialized. From the error message it does appear to be a null pointer, but there is nothing in the code in the question that would do that. There are situations where it would be a null pointer, but don’t count on it! +1.

Comment: Thx Pete! the error went away! I'm kinda new to OOP and it's really confusing

Answer (score 1):

Your `cardNumber` field is a pointer that always equals a garbage value, which means it does not point a memory area that is specifically meant for the values you would like to associate with the name, but points to some occasional memory address - your program is not correct, and you must expect everything possible (and that sometimes it would finish with a correct result).

Since you are going to store always fixed number of chars there, the best option for it would be change type of the field from the pointer to an array - this would preserve a memory area specifically for storing the values (in the example I use std::array, which is a container that encapsulates fixed size arrays for no additional run-time resources).

```
...
    
#include <array>
    
...
    
        constexpr static size_t cardNumber_Size = 20;
        std::array<char, cardNumber_Size> cardNumber;
    
...

            for (int i = 0; i < cardNumber.size(); i++) {

...
```